# MongoDB append simple java data types as 'Object' to a document fields

Tags: mongodb

I'm just starting with MongoDB.

I have a Map<String, Object> that contains several data types as a values. For example:
{ "price":235837210, "name":"hello", "position":1, "onAir":false, ... }

Now I'm trying to append these elements to a MongoDB Document as follows:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
 document.append(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

As a result I get the following exception:

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class [Ljava.lang.Object;.
```

The use case is much more complicated, but the question is if I can do this in any way in order to avoid specific casting. Something like:

```
document.append("price", (long)map.get("price"));
```

Thanks,
Joan.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was a problem with using Object[] instead of ArrayList.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).